# How to convert array to a string using methods other than JSON?

Tags: php, arrays, string-conversion

What is a function in PHP used to convert array to string, other than using JSON?

I know there is a function that directly does like JSON. I just don't remember.

Comment: what would be a typical input and what kind of result do you expect from the converted array?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

[`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/function.serialize.php) is the function you are looking for.  It will return a string representation of its input array or object in a PHP-specific internal format. The string may be converted back to its original form with `unserialize()`.

But beware, that not all objects are serializable, or some may be only partially serializable and unable to be completely restored with `unserialize()`.

```
$array = array(1,2,3,'foo');
echo serialize($array);

// Prints
a:4:{i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;s:3:"foo";}
```

Answer (score 46):

Use the [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function:

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone
```

Answer (score 20):

### **readable output!**

```
echo json_encode($array);     //outputs--->    "name1":"value1",  "name2":"value2",  ...
```

OR

```
echo print_r($array, true);
```

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/function.serialize.php). Here is an example:

```
$array = array('foo', 'bar');

//Array to String
$string = serialize($array);

//String to array
$array = unserialize($string);
```

Answer (score 8):

Another good alternative is http_build_query

```
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'cow'=>'milk',
              'php'=>'hypertext processor');

echo http_build_query($data) . "\n";
echo http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;');
```

Will print

```
foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
foo=bar&amp;baz=boom&amp;cow=milk&amp;php=hypertext+processor
```

More info here http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Answer (score 5):

use php `implode()` or `serialize()`

Answer (score 3):

Display array in beautiful way:

```
function arrayDisplay($input)
{
    return implode(
        ', ',
        array_map(
            function ($v, $k) {
                return sprintf("%s => '%s'", $k, $v);
            },
            $input,
            array_keys($input)
        )
    );
}

$arr = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'cow'=>'milk',
              'php'=>'hypertext processor');

echo arrayDisplay($arr);
```

Displays:

```
foo => 'bar', baz => 'boom', cow => 'milk', php => 'hypertext processor'
```

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to do this some of them has given.
`implode(), join(), var_export(), print_r(), serialize(), json_encode()`exc... You can also write your own function without these:

A `For()` loop is very useful. You can add your array's value to another variable like this:

```
<?php
    $dizi=array('mother','father','child'); //This is array

    $sayi=count($dizi);
    for ($i=0; $i<$sayi; $i++) {
        $dizin.=("'$dizi[$i]',"); //Now it is string...
    }
         echo substr($dizin,0,-1); //Write it like string :D
?>
```

In this code we added $dizi's values and comma to $dizin:

`$dizin.=("'$dizi[$i]',");`

Now

```
$dizin = 'mother', 'father', 'child',
```

It's a string, but it has an extra comma :)

And then we deleted the last comma, `substr($dizin, 0, -1);`

Output:

> 'mother','father','child'