# array to string conversion return error of stdClass

Tags: php, json, type-conversion

```
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $user = $stmt->get_result();
        while ($obj = $user->fetch_object()) {
             $result[] = $obj;
        }
    }

$result1encoded = json_encode($result);
echo $result1encoded;
// [{"uId":"1","firstName":"John"}]
```

I used implode like this :

```
    echo $result1encoded = implode(' ',$result1);
// expecting '[{"uId":"1","firstName":"John"}]'
```

But it says

```
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

Comment: $result1 is array of object. So, as array elements are objects here, they cannot be converted to string. implode expects string elements.

Comment: why you wan to use `implode` when you are already getting result using `json_encode`

Comment: Can you post the `print_r($result);` ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [uId] => 1 [firstName] => John ) )

Comment: @user3522462, Did you check the answers below ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_map("json_encode", $your_array)` to first convert each element of the array to string, and then use `implode` to glue it together.

See this https://eval.in/141541

```
<?php

$a = array();

$a[0]  = new stdClass();
$a[0]->uId = "1";
$a[0]->firstName = "John";

$a[1]  = new stdClass();
$a[1]->uId = "2";
$a[1]->firstName = "Albert";

$b = array_map("json_encode", $a);
echo implode(' ', $b);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert Array to String you can use `serialize()` method like this

```
$result1encoded = json_encode($result);

echo serialize($result1encoded);
```

Another Way to do is

```
 $result1encoded = json_encode($result);

echo $result1 = implode(' ',$result1encoded);


|**Edited Part**|
```

Please go through flowing link hope it solves ur problem
[Array to String Conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817148/ways-to-convert-array-to-string-in-php)

Comment: your first solution I got something like s59 in front of it. your second suggestion didnt work.

Comment: go through that link that I have edited now I hope u can solve your solutions Thanks

Comment: I did it and I got the flowing out put by the second method I use like this  `echo $result1 = implode(" ", $result1encoded);` and the out puts are  `[{"id":"1","ProductType":"iPhone"},{"id":"2","ProductType":"iPad"},{"id":"3","ProductType":"iMac"},{"id":"4","ProductType":"Accessories"}]`