# PHP Change array to string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array come back from a query but I want to change it to a string for another db query

```
$test = $go->get_stuff();
$test = array(
    'ONE',
    'TWO',
    'THREE',
    'FOUR'
)

// expected outcome
$sql .= "(table.col IN ('ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR') OR table.col IS NULL)";
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Please, please, please: use prepared statements. Don't just string together queries: Injection is very real, and very common

Comment: It also sounds like what you REALLY want is to join two tables together - unning a query, getting an array, and then running another query on that array - just use a JOIN in your SQL.

Comment: Seems to me like you could use a `JOIN` here rather than creating two queries?

Comment: This is an accident waiting to happen. As someone else already pointed out; prepare your queries. Don't just blatantly put text straight into your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implode the array:

```
$str = "'" . implode("', '", $test) . "'";
```

Then you can add it to your SQL:

```
$sql .= "(table.col IN ($str) OR table.col IS NULL)";
```

Comment: You're missing the quotes

Comment: @danmullen this will result in `ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR` (missing quotes)

Comment: Thanks knew I had to use implode but just couldnt figure out getting the quotes in

Answer (score 2):

Use `implode()` but also be sure to preppend and append a single quote as well:

```
$string = "'" . implode("','", $test) . "'";
// 'ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR'
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered before here: [How to convert array to a string using methods other than JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817148/ways-to-convert-array-to-string-in-php)

Essentially, you will need to use the [implode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) for your data set.

```
$test = $go->get_stuff();
$test = array(
    'ONE',
    'TWO',
    'THREE',
    'FOUR'
)

// Implode array to string
$string = "'" . implode("','", $test) . "'";
// Deliver desired output
$sql .= "(table.col IN (".$string.") OR table.col IS NULL)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `implode()`. Try this..

```
$in = "'".implode("','", $test)."'";
$sql .= "(table.col IN (".$in.") OR table.col IS NULL)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to foreach and rtrim:
`foreach($test as $v) { $str .= "'$v',"; } $str = rtrim($str, ',');`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with "implode" function.

Try this:

```
$test = $go->get_stuff();
$test = array(
    'ONE',
    'TWO',
    'THREE',
    'FOUR'
)

// expected outcome
$sql .= "(table.col IN ('".implode("','", $test)."') OR table.col IS NULL)";
```